# Missing initials when profile photo not selected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Changes I have made to user name registration due to client request we are using the first name, middle name, and last name in the user model I set up a function to bring them all into one.

```php
    public function getFullNameAttribute($value) {
        return ucfirst($this->firstname) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->middle_name) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->lastname);
    }
```

I am using this in several places like:

```html
    <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover" src="{{ Auth::user()->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ Auth::user()->fullname }}" />
```

Could this be the reason I am not getting the initials on the page and am just getting a bluish cercal?

And if so what can do I to fix it?

Comment: Are your column names correct? You have conflicting cases between `firstname` and `lastname` (no underscore) vs `middle_name` (underscore). Also, `ucfirst()` doesn't return the initial, it simply converts `example` to `Example` (upper-case the first letter)

Comment: Normally the initials are put in if you haven’t selected a photo; this is all I am trying to have happen. We are of the opinion that it is not happening because we change from name to fullname and are trying to figure out how to get the initials back in the cercal.

Comment: Ah I see; this is used in the `alt="..."` tag; gotcha. I think you might need to update your question with some CSS and/or screenshots of the problem before and after the change; I'm having trouble visualizing your issue.

Comment: `Auth::user()->full_name`

Comment: Create a new laravel 8 site using Jetstream laravel new “your project”  --jet.
Next go to config\jetstream.php and enable the Features::profilephotos(),
Now go to the project in a browser  and register and login on the dashboard at the top you will see the blush cercal with your initials in it.